# Xcode 9 - no iOS 11 simulator

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, ios11, xcode9-beta, xcode9

When I open up the new Xcode 9 and go to `Preferences > Components` I don't see an option to download iOS 11 simulators. I'm 100% sure I have the latest Xcode 9 beta 4 [image: No iOS 11 sims :(]

I did some research and found out that Xcode downloads an index to determine what it is able to download. For me that was: 
https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/index-9.0.0-CA351AD8-3176-41CB-875C-42A05C7CDEC7.dvtdownloadableindex

Basically one is able to use it for any Xcode version by determining the DTXcoce:
`defaults read /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Info DTXcode` .
A result like `0900` must be converted to `9.0.0`

And the DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUID:
`defaults read /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Info DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUID`

Then download: `https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/index-<the DTXcode>-<the UUID>.dvtdownloadableindex` .

And lastly in order to be able to open it: `plutil -convert xml1 <the downloaded .dvtdownloadableindex file>`

Can someone verify I have the right dvtdownloadableindex? Or provide a url to the right version? Otherwise I hope someone can provide the url for the complete simulator package by downloading and cancelling the simulator while looking in to `console.app` like in [this article](https://hackernoon.com/manually-install-ios-simulators-in-xcode-f7e4bbe50753)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I seem to be pretty stupid, wasting too much time than necessary.
The new iOS 11 simulators were already included in the new Xcode, (however the won't appear in the settings of Xcode) . You can just open up the simulator (`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app`) and choose an iOS 11 device in the `Hardware > Device` menu bar.

`Xcode.app` can be `Xcode-beta.app` too.

Answer (score 14):

In Xcode Version 9.0 beta 5 (9M202q)

In the menu **Window > Devices and Simlators**

1. Click on the + button at the bottom left corner
2. Choose 'Device Type': 'iPhone SE'
3. Then 'OS Version': 'iOS 11.0' can be choosen

[image]

Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

[image]Just go to "File" in the simulation window, move your mouse to "Open device", select your ios , and finally select the type of iPhone or device you want.

Comment: You couldn't provide a screenshot, could you?

Comment: I can if you need it

Comment: Hey @paul. It's not that I need that. I was recommending it because screenshots improve the quality of your answer if somebody can't find a particular thing. :)
Also, you can see above, that the answer with the embedded screenshot got more upvotes. Maybe you can delete your second answer below with the imgur link and instead update this answer by embedding the image. Let me know if you run into any issues.

Answer (score 0):

When I open up the new Xcode 9 and go to Preferences > Components I don't see an option to download iOS 11 simulators. I'm 100% sure I have the latest Xcode 9 beta 4
**Answered:**
Here is a screenshot, there is also another way to select the emulator you want to run but It would require an update if you have not

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZ3Ua.jpg

Comment: Just providing the link won't be helpful. You can add context in your answer!